# Как сделать такую структуру блоков?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Ребята... помогите.
Постараюсь объяснить. К примеру на сайте есть два вида блоков.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как вы видите на картинке блоки идут подряд 1,2,3,4,5
К примеру блок 3 стал в ширину как две обычные, и вверху получилось пустое место.
Как сделать так что бы в таких случаях блок 4 перемешался на пустое место.

masonry
isotop 
Это все понятно. Как то это делается без этого?

Можно js css jquery как?

Comment: Упомянутые Вами masonry и isotop распространяются с открытым исходным кодом. Если Вы считаете, что сможете сделать лучше, чем авторы этих плагинов, почему бы Вам не посмотреть как они сделаны в их исходном коде?

Comment: А кто писал что они плохие? Вам просто ляпнуть?)

Comment: @bismoney, вам просто намекнули, что можно открыть исходники этих библиотек и посмотреть как там сделано.

Comment: можете пример разметки такой привести?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я уже решил написал написав небольшой скрипт.

Comment: @bismoney, в таком случае можете опубликовать его здесь и пометить в качестве принятого решения

Comment: http://packery.metafizzy.co/
masonry придется для такого использовать!